# Using Seam as the border for Square border Surface Parameterisation

Tags: cgal

Generally, Seam is a connected tree which passes through a set of vertices in a mesh. I want to use this tree as the border for the mesh to parameterize. What I did:

1. Obtained halfedge from consecutive vertices of seam tree `hd =
   sm.halfedge(v1,v2)`
2. For each obtained halfedge `sm.set_face(hd,
   Surface_mesh::null_face())` to mark this halfedge as border
   halfedge.
3. `sm.set_next(hd1,hd2)` was done to connect all the
   halfedges in a loop, which starts and ends at the same vertex

So Now I have essentially marked all the vertices of the seam tree as border vertices by setting halfedges between consectutive vertices (in both directions) to null face. This way I am able to identify the seam tree as the border.

Let `bhd` be any of the halfedge from the above. `SMP::parameterize(sm, Parameterizer(border_param), bhd, uv_map);` fails during computation of `connected_component` as the halfedge opposite to `bhd` is also pointing towards null face.

Which step am I doing wrong, Is there any work around?

Comment: Did you have a look at the Seam_mesh class. There is an example in the User Manual: https://doc.cgal.org/4.13/Surface_mesh_parameterization/index.html#title18

Comment: The example is a nice use of Seam_mesh, but it uses seam for parameterization while using the actual mesh border. I want to use the seam as the border.

Comment: It works when I find the longest border for the seam mesh instead of the underlying triangulated mesh